# "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." Use .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, where I want to filter based on criteria, change values in a few columns and then append/concat that new dataframe to the original dataframe. I can do this successfully with the following code:

```
end_previous_month = EndDate.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
end_previous_month = end_previous_month.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

df1 = df[(df['Account.DisplayID'] == "1-1110") &
     (df['CompanyKey'] != 4) &
     (df['DateOccurred'] <= end_previous_month)]
df1['Account.Name'] = 'Opening Balance'
df1['Account.DisplayID'] = '10-0001'
df1['DisplayID'] = ""

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

However, I keep getting the following warning:

```
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."
Use .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I tried doing the method the documentation mentioned, as follows:

```
end_previous_month = EndDate.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
end_previous_month = end_previous_month.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

df1 = df.copy()

m = (df['Account.DisplayID'] == "1-1110") &
    (df['CompanyKey'] != 4) &
    (df['DateOccurred'] <= end_previous_month)

df1.loc[m, ['Account.Name', 'Account.DisplayID', 'DisplayID']] = ['Opening Balance', '10-0001', ""]

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

However, this doesn't filter the dataframe, it just isolates the values I want to change and then appends the entire dataframe onto the existing dataframe. Is there a way to accomplish my desired result without receiving the warning and appending the entire dataframe onto itself? i.e. I only want to append my filtered selection.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I worked it out.

```
end_previous_month = EndDate.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
end_previous_month = end_previous_month.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

df1 = df[(df['Account.DisplayID'] == "1-1110") &
     (df['CompanyKey'] != 4) &
     (df['DateOccurred'] <= end_previous_month)].copy()

df1.loc[:, ['Account.Name', 'Account.DisplayID', 'DisplayID']] =
           ['Opening Balance', '10-0001', ""]

df = pd.concat([df, df1])
```